# multi threading storm Bolt parallelism

Tags: multithreading, apache-kafka, apache-storm

Components for Testing are

**Kafka Procucer** that reads a file from machine, file is composed of 1000 lines.

```
        String sCurrentLine;
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\jsonLogTest.txt"));
        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            //System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
            KeyedMessage<String, String> message =new KeyedMessage<String, String>(TOPIC,sCurrentLine);
            producer.send(message);
        }
```

**Storm Consumer** with Three Bolts, BoltOne is supposed to receive the stream and divide it on two different Streams (Stream1 & Stream2). BoltTwo and BoltThree should subscribe to these Streams.
(In simple words I am looking to process the tuple in BoltOne parley like Bolt2 processes first 500 lines and BolltThree last 500 lines.

Topology

```
builder.setSpout("line-reader-spout",kafkaSpout,1);
        builder.setBolt("bolt-one", new BoltOne(),1).shuffleGrouping("line-reader-spout");
        builder.setBolt("bolt-two", new BoltTwo(),1).shuffleGrouping("bolt-one","stream1");
        builder.setBolt("bolt-three", new BoltThree(),1).shuffleGrouping("bolt-one","stream2");
```

BoltOne

```
collector.emit("stream1", new Values(input.getString(0)));
            collector.emit("stream2", new Values(input.getString(0)));
        x++;System.out.println("" + x);
        collector.ack(input);

public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer outputFieldsDeclarer) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        outputFieldsDeclarer.declareStream("stream1", new Fields("field1"));
        outputFieldsDeclarer.declareStream("stream2", new Fields("field2"));
    }
```

BoltTwo & BoltThree

```
public void execute(Tuple input) {
        String sentence = input.getString(0);
        System.out.println("*********B2*************");

    }
```

StackTrace

```
*********B2*************
1
*********B3*************
2
*********B2*************
*********B3*************
3
*********B3*************
*********B2*************
4
*********B3*************
*********B2*************
5
*********B2*************
*********B3*************
6
*********B2*************
*********B3*************
7
*********B3*************
*********B2*************
```

Totally confused with splitting streams and parallelism. Example would be helpful.

**Updated Solution** I came up with for now :

```
public void execute(Tuple input) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        String sentence = input.getString(0);
        if (x%2==0) {
            collector.emit("stream1", new Values(input.getString(0)));
        }
        else{
            collector.emit("stream2", new Values(input.getString(0)));
        }

        x++;
        collector.ack(input);
    }
```

I just divided the stream on even-Odd basis, and the time to process becomes half, While the BoltTwo processes a tuple other is processed by BoltThree.

Comment: have you gone thorough [this](http://storm.apache.org/releases/0.10.0/Understanding-the-parallelism-of-a-Storm-topology.html)?

Comment: Achieved it somehow by:
public void execute(Tuple input) {
  @SuppressWarnings("unused")
  String sentence = input.getString(0);
  if (x%2==0) {
   collector.emit("stream1", new Values(input.getString(0)));
  }
  else{
   collector.emit("stream2", new Values(input.getString(0)));
  }
     
        x++;
  collector.ack(input);
 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you run everything using `LocalCluster`. As there are multiple threads running, the output via `println(...)` is not synchronized and internal buffering can mess up the order of the output... Thus, the stuff you see in not reliable -- the order is only preserved within a single spout/bolt.

Furthermore, what is the behavior you want to get?

Right now, you have

```
Spout => Bolt1 =+=> Bolt2
                +=> Bolt3
```

Ie, the output of Bolt1 is duplicated and Bolt2 and Bolt3 both receive all output tuple from Bolt1. Thus, Bolt1 counts from 1 to 7, and each output tuple of Bolt1 triggers `execute()` of Bolt2 and Bolt3.

As Bolt2 and Bolt3 do the same thing, I guess you want to have two copies of the same Bolt and partition the input to both. For this, you only add a single bolt and set the parallelism to 2:

```
builder.setSpout("line-reader-spout",kafkaSpout,1);
builder.setBolt("bolt-one", new BoltOne(),1).shuffleGrouping("line-reader-spout");
builder.setBolt("bolt-two", new BoltTwo(),2).shuffleGrouping("bolt-one","stream1");
```

Furthermore, Bolt1 only need to declare a single output stream (and not two). If you declare multiple output streams and write to both, you replicate the data...